# Snowflake Create table with subset of columns populated from Select statement

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

On Snowflake is there a way to create table  with subset of columns populated from Select statement from other tables ?

From the examples I see on documentation, we can either populate all the columns through Select from other tables or populate none of the columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to select `NULL` cast to the desired data type, with an alias as part of the `SELECT` statement.

```
CREATE TABLE t1 AS
SELECT
    col1,
    col2,
    NULL::timestamp_ntz AS col3,
    NULL::number AS col4
FROM t2;
```

This example would create a table `t1` with four columns, two of which come from `t2`.

Answer (score 0):

The hive mind fed me this solution today. It brings all the columns except one (or more).

```
create table t1 as 
select * except( field ) from t2;
```

Should be good on snowflake.